# Android - UI actionbar gets skewed on a tablet

Tags: android, screen, android-relativelayout

I am looking to develop an app with an actionbar that will work on all sizes of screens. I have a RelativeLayout which does it. If I specify height as 50, it appears larger and stretched on tablet devices. How do I go about it? I am an Android novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the following link -

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I ran into the same issue a few days back and converted px to dpi. Now it shows up fine on all sizes!